# typescript type conversion with prisma

Tags: typescript, types, prisma

I would like to change my 'createdAt' format using Typescipt, and Prisma ORM.

```
const post = await prisma.post.find({ where: { id: 1 }})

post.createdAt = moment(post.createdAt)

return post

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'
```

I totally understand why this error occurs, but I don't know how to solve it efficiently.
what should I do now?
Should I make a new interface or a custom type every time I call data from db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update the Prisma client generated type definition for `Post.createdAt` to accomodate a `moment` object type. This is what it might look like

```js
import { Post } from "@prisma/client";  // Prisma client generated definition of Post

type customPost = Omit<Post, 'createdAt'> & {
  createdAt: Date | moment.Moment | string  // moment constructor returns object of type moment.Moment, so adding that in addition to string.
}

async function foo() {
    const post : customPost = await prisma.post.find({ where: { id: 1 }})
    post.createdAt = moment(post.createdAt)  
    return post
}
```

The [omit utility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is used to first erase the original definition of `createdAt` before redefining it.

Comment: How about when using a create() statement, I'm using a middleware that converts to another field type, but I'm getting TS errors before the middleware is reached