# Type casting in prisma

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I have one doubt on the prisma query, how can I do type casting in the prisma query,
In my case, I need to perform where query against the datetime values, Here the input will be either one of the strings or a timestamp. if the input is a timestamp value, then it works fine, if the value is not a timestamp value, then the prisma throws an error.

```
 return this.DB.$transaction([
      this.User.findMany({
        take,
        skip,
        where: {
              created_at:{ equals: '2022-10-03T05:24:04.712Z'}
           }
      }),
      this.User.count({
        where: { ...queries, ...columnQuery }
      })
    ])
```

In the above case, the query works fine, if I provide the string instead of the timestamp it throw an error

```
 return this.DB.$transaction([
      this.User.findMany({
        take,
        skip,
        where: {
           created_at:{equals: '12'}
       }
      }),
      this.User.count({
        where: { ...queries, ...columnQuery }
      })
    ])
```

Here the order by input is 12, if the value is not a time stamp type, I also need to perform the where query. In my understaing, if we perform the typecasting to string against created_at column, we can perform filter query in typestamp datatype column, even though the input is not a timestamp type

friends can you help me to fix this ?

Comment: Here's a related Stack Overflow Answer which demonstrates the same thing you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756331/typescript-type-conversion-with-prisma